# How to replace columns with first rows RSHINY

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Here is my shiny app. Now I cant be able o share data for running it but basically this app has multiple csvs saved in *./data folder*. What I am trying to do is compare each csv in two pairs of each. Now when I select CSV files from the dropdown menu and compare I have some result table with column names messed up and that means I am supposed to delete the column names and replace them with the first row of the data, Then I still have other results that I get after comparing other files and I get  right column names that I don't have to replace.

```
library("shiny")
library(daff)
library(dplyr)
library(shinythemes)
library("DT")
library(readr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(janitor)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr) 
library(plyr)

setwd("path")
ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Automated Data Dictionary Comparison"),
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput(inputId = 'Dic1',
                  label = 'Choose First Data Dictionary:',

                  choices = list.files(path = "./data",
                                       full.names = FALSE,
                                       recursive = FALSE)),
      selectInput(inputId = 'Dic2',
                  label = 'Choose Second Data Dictionary:',
                  choices = list.files(path = "./data",
                                       full.names = FALSE,
                                       recursive = FALSE)),
      actionButton("do", "Replace columns"),

      tags$hr(),
      # This one is linked by the id 'download'
      downloadButton('download',"Download the data")


    ),


    mainPanel (
      tabsetPanel(
       tabPanel('Html Table',
         HTML("<div style ='overflow:auto; height:500px; width:800px ' >"),
         uiOutput('contents'),
         HTML("</div>")
       ),
       tabPanel('Diff Table',
                fluidRow(
                  column(div(DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"), style = "font-size: 75%; width: 75%"),width = 12)
                )


       ),

       tabPanel("Modified table",
                fluidRow(
                  column(div(DT::dataTableOutput("modified"), style = "font-size: 75%; width: 75%"),width = 12)
                )
       ),
       tabPanel("Added table",
                fluidRow(
                  column(div(DT::dataTableOutput("added"), style = "font-size: 75%; width: 75%"),width = 12)
                )
       )
      )



      )
    )
)


server = function(input, output){    
  # Parse first file
  dataset1 <- reactive({

    infile <- input$Dic1

    if (is.null(infile)){
      return(NULL)
    }
    x <- read.csv(paste0("./data/", infile[[1]]))
    x
  })
  # Parse second file
  dataset2 <- reactive({

    infile <- input$Dic2

    if (is.null(infile)){
      return(NULL)
    }
    x <- read.csv(paste0("./data/", infile[[1]]))
    x
  })

  # Create difference table then save
  diff1 <- reactive( {
    dd <- diff_data(data_ref=dataset1(), data=dataset2())
    write_diff(dd, "./data/diffrev.csv")

    diff_df <- readr::read_csv("./data/diffrev.csv")
    ft <-as.data.frame(lapply(diff_df, iconv, from = 'UTF-8', to = 'UTF-8'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ft


  })




  output$mytable <- renderDataTable({

   diff1()

  },options = list(scrollX = TRUE))


  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){"thename.csv"}, 
    content = function(fname){
      write.csv(thedata(), fname)})

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My first question is how can I smartly delete and replace column names with the first row once I display the **diff1 table** output? I am thinking of using an action button which I can be able to delete those tables with unwanted columns but it will still delete wanted columns from the output.

What I expect is once I see unwanted columns in the output , I can replace them but once I see wanted columns in the output, I should choose to keep them

Comment: Please share some data, even synthetic.

Comment: I'm not able to fully understand what the problem is. Is it with reading a CSV with or without column names? with `data_diff` when the column names are different? Some other issue? Is this directly related to `shiny`?

Comment: @Omri374  The thing is I select on file from first dropdown and compare with second file from second dropdown.The problem I need assistance is with the output I get in renderDatatable. There are file which ones I compare the output has messed up columns which I simply want to replace with first row but I still have comparisons which come with right columns names in the output, I dont need to replace them.Question is how can I after seeing the output choose to replace or keep the column names?

Comment: Please add a fully reproducible example. I have no idea how your two data frames look like so I can't reproduce this